# React Boostrap - TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have created a new react app with react version as 16.6.3.
 I added the react-bootstrap version0.28.5. However when i run my app, i get "React Boostrap - TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined "error.

This is the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"file-saver": "^2.0.0",
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.28.5",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-overlays": "^0.7.0",
"react-router": "^3.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts-scss-ts": "2.17.1",
"react-search-input": "^0.11.3"
```

}

I also ran "npm dedupe" to find any duplicate issues but with no luck. Is there any way i could fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like [an issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2883) from React version. The link provides some workaround, check if that's your case

Comment: I did try that link but did not help..still getting the same error